# How to add trusted origin to bot's direct line channel without using Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, botframework, azure-cli, azure-bot-service

I need to be able to stand up a bot and the associated web page entirely from inside an Azure DevOps release pipeline. On the bot, I need to add the direct line channel (this operation is currently supported). I also need to add a trusted origin. I don't believe it's possible to do this from the command line.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this by adding an [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) to your pipeline.

From here you have two options:

1) Use the `az resource update` command:

```
az resource update --name web --resource-group myResourceGroup --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type config --parent sites/<app_name> --set properties.cors.allowedOrigins="['http://localhost:5000']" --api-version 2015-06-01
```

The documentation is [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#enable-cors).

2) Use the `az webapp cors` command:

```
az webapp cors add -g {myRG} -n {myAppName} --allowed-origins https://myapps.com
```

The documentation for this command is [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/cors?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: I'm going to try this soon. Will edit to tell you if it works.

Comment: How did you get on @EricHansen?

Comment: Work has me pulled in too many directions to test immediately. Will edit to tell you if it works.